# Converting an HTML element to a String/Object

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-maps, html-to-text

I'm creating an AngularJS app that basically has a table and a search bar. The table is locations, and when you click on a link its supposed to take you to said location via an embedded Google Map. Im having trouble with the Map when I try to Pan it to the new location. Here is what the app looks:[image: SiteSearch App]

Is there anyway to be able to click on a name/coordinates (name is preferred so I can remove the coordinates column) and convert the coordinates to a string/object that I can use to set a location on Google Maps?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Doesn't seem to have anything to do with angularjs, I'd remove that tag.  tostring seems a bit dubious as well.

Comment: you can use [angular-google-map](http://angular-google-maps.org/#!/)

Comment: what do you mean? @HarishR

Comment: It may be easier just put a href target on the coordinates like:
https://www.google.com/maps/place/33%C2%B024'55.8%22N+91%C2%B003'22.9%22E/@33.4134394,91.05636,9z

Comment: Yeah thats what I did before but I need the app to run offline. @JesseRules